# iPhone App Dev - Loading a view into another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a root view controller with just a simple navigation button that loads a questionview. When I use pushViewController a back button appears. Instead I want a custom button in the top right of the uinavigationcontroller and I want to remove the back button after the page transition.

how can i achieve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at UINavigationItem. You can accomplish both your goals by properly configuring your view controller's navigation item. Use the `-setHidesBackButton:animated:` to hide the back button, and the `-setRightBarButtonItem:animated:` to add your custom button on the right side of the navigation bar.